# Cytoscape is crashe during the ClueGO processing

Tags: crash, cytoscape.js

I've been using Cytoscape version 3.9.1 along with ClueGO version 2.5.10, and everything was working smoothly until I attempted to update the Gene Ontology source. Unfortunately, the update process failed three times. Subsequently, when I ran ClueGO for enrichment analysis, Cytoscape crashed and abruptly closed during the final step.

In an attempt to resolve the issue, I upgraded Cytoscape to version 3.10.1, which also included an upgrade to Java. However, even with this update, the same problem persisted, and ClueGO crashed at the final step once again.
I'm seeking guidance on how to address this recurring issue. Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to provide an update on the issue I was facing, and I managed to resolve it on my own. It turns out that I needed to update CluePedia as well. After making this update, I found that Cytoscape version 3.10.1, Java version 17, ClueGO version 2.5.10, and CluePedia version 1.5.10 worked seamlessly together without any issues.
I hope this information can be helpful to others who may encounter a similar problem.